# Cassandra - Distributed Row Locking for Select AND Update

Tags: java, concurrency, cassandra, microservices, azure-cosmosdb

I have a micro-service which runs on multiple machines in two regions which connects to Cassandra DB. I have the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE gifts (
  gift_id text,
  user_id text
  PRIMARY KEY gift_id
);
```

The table contains a list of gift id.

During multiple concurrent request each user must be assigned a unique gift i.e select a random gift_id and update the user_id.

Will LWT be helpful to solve this problem?

**Limitations:**

- Cannot use zookeeper for locking
- Cannot use any relational database.

Comment: You're using Cosmos, so it's worth noting that LWT isn't fully supported in Cosmos (e.g. single-region only).

Answer (score 2):

Note that LWT doesn't affect `SELECT`s.  The usual last-writer-wins and tunable consistency semantics apply (though running a `SELECT` with consistency level `ALL` guarantees that you'll see the write from the latest `INSERT`/`UPDATE` (which in Cassandra should best be considered the same: `INSERT` has upsert semantics)).

You can use `LWT`s to ensure that no two users share a `gift_id`.  Simply `INSERT` with `IF NOT EXISTS` if once a gift is associated with a user it can't be associated with any other user.  Alternatively, you can do a `SELECT user_id FROM gifts WHERE gift_id = ...` and then `INSERT` with `IF user_id = the_user_id_from_the_select`.